# Best Practice in calling another object from a collection to another collection in noSQL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm new to NoSQL so I need an opinion on how the flow on how noSQL works.

I'm trying to make an employee rewards website where users can use points to redeem rewards such as vouchers, and coupons, etc.

Therefore, what I imagine is there will be a user collection and a rewards collection where a document in a users collection will store basic user information as well as user points. Rewards collection will store document that contains the info of certain rewards such as the points to redeem and their quantity etc.

Is it the best solution to create an inventory for users to store the rewards bought from the rewards page (from the rewards collection) in another collection called userRewards which calls the rewardsID from the rewards collection and the user collection will have another entity called userInventory where it calls the userRewardsID? So will the user Inventory entity save the userRewardsID as an array, because some say it is not good practice?

This is how I imagine the flow

```
User                              Rewards       UserRewards      
----                              -----       ---------------  
ID                                 ID          ID               
Name                               Name        RewardsID           
Phone                              Quantity    ClaimStatus  
Email                              Points
UserInventory : UserRewardsID
```

Comment: In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: @AlexMamo for my project one of the main queries is to store "reward" or vouchers that is from the reward collection to the user collection as part of users inventory.

Comment: *store "reward" or vouchers* is **not** a query. Please provide the queries that we want to perform.

Comment: @AlexMamo Query rewards that belongs to a specific user, or maybe query quantity of a certain item that is bought by a user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the NoSQL world, we are structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. So according to your last comment:

> Query rewards that belong to a specific user.

Then I recommend you structure the database like this:

```
db
|
--- users (collection)
     |
     --- $uid (document)
          |
          --- //user fields
          |
          --- rewards (sub-collection)
               |
               --- $rewardId (document)
                     |
                     --- //reward fields
```

Having such a structure, you can create a collection reference that points to the `rewards` sub-collection so you can get all the rewards that correspond to a specific user. Besides that, please also note that [there are no JOINS in Firestore](https://www.tiktok.com/@alex_mamo/video/7309764071375637793).

Answer (score 0):

You want to UNLEARN what you know about SQL.

NoSQL is not SQL.  SQL is the evil twin of NoSQL.

You do NOT want to use "references" and "JOINs" in NoSQL.  Instead...embrace DATA DUPLICATION (i.e. data DEnormalization).

Here's [an article on that](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/designing-firestore-collections-documents) that I wrote.

Comment: Could you please add disclosure to this answer and your [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A229326+url%3Abuymeacoffee.com)? That way, people won't flag your answers as spam.